# this.router.navigateByUrl routing fine, but not displaying HTML content

Tags: angular

I have my routes as follows:

```
 {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'platform', component: PlatformComponent,
    children: [
    ...
    ...
```

and app.component.html with just the following content:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and then on app.component.ts the following code at the constructor {}:

```
  this._router.navigateByUrl("/login");
```

After the user enters the email and password, if validated, Im doing

```
this.router.navigate(['../platform/maindashboard'], { relativeTo: this.activeRoute });
```

I also did

```
this.router.navigateByUrl("/platform/maindashboard");
```

but in both cases (even if Im being routed to the correct route) a blank page is displayed. I checked the HTML code on the page and its all there, but nothing is being rendered.

I've been dealing with this for hours already and I cannot find a solution to this.

Thanks so much.

Comment: make sure you add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on your `platform` component to show its children component's template

Comment: Hey Stavm. <router-outlet> is there at the platform component. This is super weird. I even ng serve several times just in case, but the problem persists. Crazy.

Comment: please try reproducing on https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy and share the link

Comment: Can you please show us your console log when page is showing blank

Comment: Stavm, I will try to reproduce the code. Dako, the console is SUPER clean, only has [WDS] Live Reloading enabled. when I save the project, and nothing new when re-routing. I also did a console.log("route loaded") and it does show up on the console, but the HTML still blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have  inside a div containing a class? Something like

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div
```

Check deleting the class and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

recently i had the same problem and it was solved by changing

```
{path: 'platform', component: PlatformComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'maindashboard',
    component: MainComponent
  }
...
...
```

to this

```
{path: 'platform',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: PlatformComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'maindashboard',
        component: MainComponent
      }
    ...
    ...
```

i don't really know the difference but it worked